# Object: Directory error: did not understand #name

Tags: directory, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

Following simple code to list files in a directory is from [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Non-recursively#Smalltalk):

```
(Directory name: '.')  
allFilesMatching: '*.st' 
do: [ :f | (f name) displayNl ]
```

However, it is not working and giving following error:

```
$ gst mysrc.st
Object: Directory error: did not understand #name:
MessageNotUnderstood(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
Directory class(Object)>>doesNotUnderstand: #name: (SysExcept.st:1448)
UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (firstline.st:1)
```

I am working on *GNU Smalltalk* version 3.2.5 on Debian Stable *Linux*.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know who has written it on the *rosettacode*, but the `#name:` selector is incorrect (does not exist in the `Directory` class).  If you check the [`Directory class`](https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual-base/html_node/Directory.html#index-Directory) you won't find such selector there.  Instead you will find a `#working:` selector.  The selector has a description:

```
working: dirName
    Change the current working directory to dirName.
```

Your code will then look like this:

```
(Directory working: '.') allFilesMatching: '*.st' do: [ :f | 
   (f name) displayNl
]
```

Comment: Why do we need `(f name) displayNl`? I see that `f displayNl` also works.

Comment: You need to look at the stdout carefully to notice the difference.  The `f displayNl` will work but it returns different output.  The sending a message `#name`  to `f` gives you whole the `name` (and path in this case) of the file (which is an instalce of a String).  Sending only `displayNl` will give you the instance of a File (you will see the double quotes).  You can try to do this in the block `[ :f | f isFile printNl ]` and `[ :f | f name isString printNl ]`.

Comment: @rnso do you understand the difference now?

Comment: Yes, very well explained. Why `(Directory working: '.')` should be in parentheses and not `allFilesMatching: '*.py'` ? Also `ff name` may not be in parentheses - it works both ways.

Comment: @rnso those are different issues.  I'll address them step-by-step: **1.** is message `#allFilesMatching:do:` (`#allFilesMatching: aStringMask do: aBlock`) the whole is one message so you can't have #allFilesMatching: which would be different message.  You are sending the message to the result of `Directory working: '.'` and not sending this message to `Directory`.  **2**. The `ff name` is using them just for readability.  It makes it easier for anyone reading the code to see that there is something done and then the result is printed.

Comment: Tukan, the documentation you pointed to in this answer seems to indicate that `Directory` is a subclass of `File`. If that is correct, then `Directory` should understand `#name:` as it is implemented in `File` (class side).

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia you are right, I'll have to check it tomorrow if the structure did change or what, why it does not work at the GNU Smalltalk I have tried, thank you for noticing it.

Comment: Also note that the semantics of `#working:` is different from the semantics of `#name:`. The former will change the current working directory while the latter will just create an instance of the desired folder. This is why `#name:` would have been better in this case.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia apparently the link is really really old.  Did not find the date on the page, but on other link, on the same page I found out that it is from 1991.  In the most current documentation the superclass of Directory is an Object class, so the `#name:` is not available like it was before.